# Instamojo payment gateway integration with java

Tags: java, payment-gateway, instamojo

Can I integrate **instamojo** `payment gateway` with **java**.

In their site (https://www.instamojo.com/developers/) nothing saying about integration with `java`.

If yes, from where I can get the documentation.

Someone can help me..

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The link to the java wrapper is available on the same page(https://www.instamojo.com/developers/) under libraries section.

Shoot out a mail to us at support@instamojo.com if you face any issues while integrating.

Comment: I was also looking for Java wrapper. The wrapper available at github is for v2.0 which is in Beta and also lacking some basic fuctionality (like webhook in Payment Order). Is there any such wrapper available for v1.1?

Comment: @NavedAlam: currently we do not have any wrappers for v1.1. You can still use our rest apis for v1.1.